# Asp.Net Change a value from another page

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have 2 webpage in my asp.net project.
I defined a int value in second page.
i want to change int value from first page. How can I make this?

Comment: Use a session variable, store and modify it in the web.config, use a database value, ...

Comment: Erm...can you please edit your question to be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the variable directly. But you can use Session to achieve this.

In Page 1

```
Session["session-name"] = "5";
```

In Page 2

```
      if (Session["session-name"] != null) // check the session if it is exist
            {
                int a;
                try
                {
                    a = int.Parse(Session["session-name"].ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    a = 0; // you can set null too. Whatever you want
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use **Session Variables**. You can [start learning here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).